# "no applicable method" error when calculating moving average with function filter()

Tags: r

Could someone please be so kind and point out what the problem with this code is:

```
mav <- function(x, n = 5) { filter(x, rep(1 / n, n), sides = 1) }

Close <- c(21000, 23400, 26800, 21000, 23400, 26800)
SourceData <- data.frame(Close)
SourceData$CloseMA1 <- mav(SourceData$Close, n = 2)
```

I am getting:

```
Error in UseMethod("filter_") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter_' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `stats::filter`. You can also check `environment(filter)` for what package your `filter` comes from.

Comment: does stats::filter use the base one? environment(filter) => environment: namespace:dplyr